# How to make content editable with button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make the input type text field editable on click with button but it is not working properly. tried all possible thing any suggestion please

```
<html><body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
     $('#btnEdit').click(function()
     {
       $("input[name='name']").removeAttr("readonly");  
     });

     });

     </script>
    <?php
    require_once ('connectdb.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM general_information";
    $result = $dbhandle->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
    <form>
    <input type = "text" name = "name" value = <?php echo $row["email"];?> readonly>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEdit" > edit </button>
    <?php } } ?>
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: Please define "_not working properly_". And don't use `name` as a value of `name`, or any other attribute or property of an HTML element.

Comment: Have you included jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems I see in the code,

1. Button is submitting the form and reloading the page. Use `preventDefault()` to override form submit.
2. Use `prop` instead of `removeAttr`.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#btnEdit').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
         $("input[name='name']").prop("readonly", false);  
        });
    });
   ```

**UPDATE from @cmorrissey comment.**

3. In textbox, quotes are missing in the `value` attribute

   ```
   <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $row["email"];?>" readonly>
   ```

Comment: 3. the `value` is not wrapped in `"`
4.  if more then 1 row is selected from the database there are multiple opening `form` tags, multiple buttons with the same `id`

Answer (score 1):

Your button is posting the form thus reloading the page so Change your button and give it an onclick event function like onclick="editInputField()":

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"  onclick="editInputField()">Edit</a>
```

Give the input and id:

```
<input type = "text" id = "name" name = "name" value = <?php echo $row["email"];?> readonly>
```

Then your javascript function to make the input editable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editInputField(){
   document.getElementById("name").readOnly = false;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I noticed you using jquery even though the question is tagged with javascript.
The reason why your code is not working has to do with:

1: The button as mentioned earlier so change it to:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEdit" role="button">Edit</a>
```

2: How your targeting the input field, use the field id like this:

```
$("#fieldID").removeAttr("readonly");
```

Comment: This does not explain at all _why_ OP's code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **disable** or **readOnly** attributes. Here you have two examples.

```
<input type="text" id="name"  disabled="disabled" value="Example"/>
<input type="text" id="name2"  readonly="readonly" value="Example2"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

function myFunction() {

    document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("name2").readOnly = false;

}
```